# What is the difference betwwen View position and LayoutParams position?

Tags: android, view, position

I would like to know the difference between the ImageView position field (mTop, mBottom, mLeft and mRight) and the layoutParams position field (mTop, mBottom, mLeft, mRight, mMarginLeft, mMarginTop) of the same ImageView.

I'm adding an ImageView in my main relativeLayout and if I don't setup both position parameters the image is either drawn at position 0,0 or it is a the right place but when I start a translation animation it acts like if it was at position 0,0.

Thanks for your enlightenment..